# Get attribute at JCarousel

Tags: javascript

How can i get the attribute in my JCarousel?

here is my code:

```
$(myul+'-place').jCarouselLite({
            //btnNext: rbutton, //'.vertical-button-right',
            //btnPrev: lbutton, //'.vertical-button-left',
            btnNext: '.vertical-button-down',
            btnPrev: '.vertical-button-up',
            visible: 3,
            mouseWheel: true,
            circular: false,
            vertical: true
        });
```

I need get the "btnNext" and "btnPrev".

Thanks for help.

Comment: I want execute the click event  associated to "btnNext" and "btnPrev". Do you understand?

Comment: Nope. An attribute is a part of an HTML element, not a JavaScript function. You want to execute the function that is attached to the btnNext and btnPrev? You should search for the file and find the "btnNext" and "btnPrev" variables and see what function they are calling.

Comment: Yes. Ok i'll find more on code. Thanks for help.